# Replace null by negative id number in not consecutive rows in hive

Tags: hiveql

I have this table in my database:

```
| id   | desc |
|-------------|
|  1   |   A  |
|  2   |   B  |
| NULL |   C  |
|  3   |   D  |
| NULL |   D  |
| NULL |   E  |
|  4   |   F  |
---------------
```

And I want to transform this table into a table that replace nulls by consecutive negative ids:

```
| id   | desc |
|-------------|
|  1   |   A  |
|  2   |   B  |
| -1   |   C  |
|  3   |   D  |
| -2   |   D  |
| -3   |   E  |
|  4   |   F  |
---------------
```

Anyone knows how can I do this in hive?

Answer (score 0):

Below approach works

select coalesce(id,concat('-',ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by id))) as id,desc from database_name.table_name;